# Green pixels on dark colors. Could this be because of the graphics card?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have got green pixels on my screen whenever i turn my pc on. This started when i was playing a game and suddenly there were green pixels,and my pc crashed. Now this happens every time my pc is on.
When i uninstall my Nvidia drivers the green pixels disappear.Could this be a graphics card problem.
What should i do?
    P.S Also the screen keeps blinking and saying drivers have stopped working and recovered successfully.

Comment: Can you connect any other device to your monitor? Or alternatively, can you connect any other monitor to your computer? Either option will give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a laptop or a desktop, but if it's a desktop then check if you have other ports to connect your monitor to to confirm it's not the monitor. Hooking up the monitor to another computer works too.

You can also try re-installing the drivers and see if the green pixels return or not.

Something else you could try to help debug this is to load another operating system on your computer from a USB drive to see if it would lead to the same issue. This would not involve installing a new OS on your hard drive. Let me know if you need more info on this.

**Note:** If you're loading an OS like Kali, make sure to select 'Forensic mode' so it doesn't mess with your hard drive.

As for what could be causing this, my best guess is it could be either one of the following:

1. Software (including drivers)
2. Graphics card itself
3. Monitor itself
4. Connection between the graphics card and the motherboard, or the cabling between the screen and the computer.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Interesting, from what I understood the question is asking if this could be from the graphics card, what else should they do, and what else could it be.

I believe I answered those in one way or another, it's pretty hard to get a definitive answer without further investigation though.

Anyway, should I delete my 'answer' then?